# equivalent of /dev/kmsg on windows?

Tags: c, logging, windbg, windows-kernel

I want to add a custom line to windows kernel log, from a batch file, or from cmd prompt.

In linux, I would do this by writing to `/dev/kmsg` file. Anything written to that file would be visible via `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages`.

e.g. `echo Hello world > /dev/kmsg`

I want something very similar for windows side.

I am also OK if there is a solution like `log_to_kernel.exe "my message"`, instead of redirecting to a device file. I think, there isn't concept of device "files" in windows.

The reason for requirement:
I am trying to debug some issues in a driver & for that I am running some test program, which internally makes calls to the driver in windows.
If the driver fails, I will be able to see the debug messages in the kernel windbg attached over 1394. The kernel debugger will hit a breakpoint/assert & I will not be able to check the iteration number on my target system, till I continue from windbg.
Hence I need to log the time & the test iteration number in kernel log itself, which I am planning to do via the batch file, which runs the automated tests.

Hence, I need some tool or dummy echo driver with C code, which would log my custom message in the kernel log.

In one line, I want to write a custom message to kernel log, from a user space app.

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to use `DbgPrintEx` function to write log entries if you are writing a driver,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543634(v=vs.85).aspx

Then the debugger should be able to display it.

If your application is user mode, `OutputDebugString` is the simplest,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx

You might also read about event tracing,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I believe that this function needs to be called from kernel/driver.
I need some utility to log something from user space.

I am thinking of writing a virtual driver, like com-port driver, which would in reality log to kernel.

Comment: Actually, I want to insert a message from user application, to kernel logs...
It should require support from kernel. (like /dev/kmsg in case of linux)

Comment: I hope you read OutputDebugString reference link carefully, "If the application has no debugger, the system debugger displays the string if the filter mask allows it. (Note that this function calls the DbgPrint function to display the string. For details on how the filter mask controls what the system debugger displays, see the DbgPrint function in the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) on MSDN.) If the application has no debugger and the system debugger is not active, OutputDebugString does nothing." So if you attach WinDbg to kernel, you should be able to receive the log entries.

Comment: Oh... I did not read carefully.
I will check out & try in a sample code.